# Reading data and inputting it into a new Excel file using Java POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am Currently trying to read an excel file in java, modify it and then place it into a new excel file. At the minute im just trying to place the read data straight into a new file. My question is how would you get the content from cell.getContents() straight into the new file

if (!f.exists()){

```
            String FileName = "C:\\Users\\alexp\\Desktop\\New_Export.xls";
            WritableWorkbook excel = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(FileName));
            WritableSheet sheet = excel.createSheet("Sheet1", 0);                                           

                                    for (int y = 0; y < page.getRows(); y++){

                                        for (int x = 0; x < page.getColumns(); x++){

                                            Cell cell = page.getCell(x ,y +1);
                                            CellType type = cell.getType();

                                                    if(type == CellType.LABEL){

                                                        System.out.println(cell.getContents());
                                                        Label label1 = new Label();
                                                        sheet.addCell(label1);
                                                        if(type == CellType.NUMBER){

                                                            System.out.println(cell.getContents());
                                                            Number num1 = new Number ();
                                                            sheet.addCell(num1);                                                                                

                                                        }           
                                                   }        
                                        }

                                        System.out.println(" ");

                                    }   


            System.out.println("The File Has Successfully Been Created!");

            excel.write();
            excel.close();

            }
            else{

                System.out.println("File is already created!");

            }
```

Comment: The classes `WritableWorkbook` and `WritableSheet` aren't part of Apache POI - are you possibly using a different library or wrapper?

Comment: Currently using jexcel (jxl) for the WritableWorkbook and WritableSheet. Would this cause a problem when also using POI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read each row of an Excel sheet using apache poi as follows:

```
HssfRow row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
HssfCell cell = row.getCell(columnIndex);
FormulaEvaluator fe = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvalator();
CellValue cv = fe.evaluate(cell);
```

Hope this will help you, I have typed this code from mobile, you may get some syntax error correct them it will work. Have a nice day:-)

Comment: This looks like the solution of my problem, thank you for your help. you too  :)